# How to add a Mailchimp Signup Form in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, mailchimp

I appreciate any and all feedback and will jump in and contribute to answers. I've styled a basic mailchimp signup form I want to display on my homepage as a responsive element that will change width according to screen size.

Because my theme (Arcade Pro) homepage is split into four columns of widget areas, I can't get the form to display the signup across the full screen -

see homepage example: http://demos.bavotasan.com/arcade/

Ideally, I'd like to include a signup below the font awesome icons - would this involve changing a theme file or custom css?

Any ideas? The mailchimp code has worked fine to date as a sidebar widget. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "font awesome icons"?

Comment: @kosherjellyfish If you click the link to the demo of the arcade theme, the homepage has four prominent icons across the width in light blue. These are scalable vector icons customised with css. The mailchimp-related issue isn't so much to do with the icons but that they are split into four widget areas. If it was one widget area full-width, I imagine the mailchimp signup form would work ok.

Comment: I understand you better now (think you typed Four as Font). Don't think you can just edit the CSS. You'll probably need to work out the HTML as well.

Comment: I have given you a more detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying out here: you'll probably need to edit the template manually to add in codes to accept a Lightbox (http://fancybox.net/). You can insert the MailChimp codes within the Lightbox itself.

**Assuming that you'll like to replace the contents of "Post Box" for your MailChimp form.**

[image: PostBox]

You'll need to edit the HTML of the page manually: in this case, the contents of Post-Block is found in the  container called "Container from-the-blog">.

[image: html]

What you'll need to remove from the codes is within the child DIV Class called "row", and replace it with the MailChimp codes.

```
//PARENT
<div class="container from-the-blog">
        //CHILD 
       <div class="row">
                  <!--REST OF CODING CONTAINING POST-BLOCK DETAILS-->

       </div>

</div>//END OF PARENT
```

Of course, please save a copy of the template before you dive into editing the HTML codes :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You're right about the intended positioning for the mailchimp form but just in between icons and post block content rather than replacing the block content, if that's helpful.

Comment: You'll then need to create a new DIV container to contain the MailChimp sign up form.